# jQuery :not selector is not working properly... or am I misuing it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an event listener which performs `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` on some images when the user clicks on the `li`.  Also, I trigger the first click on load, to make some dynamic stuff happen.(pop-up appending).

Now on the load I need dynamic stuff, excluding `fadeIn/fadeOut` effect, as well user click on the `li`, the animation has to work. for make this, i added a class, and i put `:not` so it would ignore the images which don't have the **.active** class. (I added class as active). once the dynamic called, I am removing that class. So, the next time user clicks, all will work as usual.

But the `:not` selector is not working. I am getting the `fadeIn/fadeOut` effect on load... How can I avoid this?

my code is :

```
if ($('div').hasClass('selsect-an-outfit')){
    $('div.selsect-an-outfit li').click(function(){
        var getUrl = $(this).children().find('img').attr('src').replace('thumb','photo');
        $('#outfit-box > img:not(.active)').fadeTo(200,0.5).fadeTo(400,1).attr('src', getUrl);
        $('<span class="layer">YOU&rsquo;RE LOOKING AT ME ALREADY <em>pick another</em></span>').appendTo($(this));
        $(this).siblings().find('span.layer').remove();
        $('#outfit-box > img').removeClass('active');
        return false;
    })
}

$('div.selsect-an-outfit li:first-child').click();
```

this is my HTML

```
<div class="selsect-an-outfit">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/thumb/feature-photo1.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/thumb/feature-photo2.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/thumb/feature-photo3.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/thumb/feature-photo4.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/thumb/feature-photo5.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/thumb/feature-photo6.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="imgs/thumb/feature-photo7.jpg"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="outfit-box">
    <img class='active' src='imgs/photo/feature-photo1.jpg' width='473' 
        height='711' alt='feature-photo'>
    <div id='outfit-top-layer'>
        <h2>special occasion</h2>
    </div>

    <p class="globe-trotting-info">
        You may not know us yet, but we’ve been selling fun, colourful 
        clothes for the whole family for almost twenty years. To help us 
        get acquainted we’ve 
    </p>

    <span><!-- swipe arrow --></span>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to:

```
$('#outfit-box > img')
    .not('.active')
    .fadeTo(200, 0.5)
    .fadeTo(400, 1)
    .attr('src', getUrl);
```

> The .not() method will end up providing you with more readable selections than pushing complex selectors or variables into a :not() selector filter. In most cases, it is a better choice.

Apparently it's the preferred and recommended way of using the not selector. [Check out my jsFiddle demonstrating](http://jsfiddle.net/mmmshuddup/N9zn3/).

Also, it appears you're missing a semi-colon at the end if your first `if`.

```
if ($('div').hasClass('selsect-an-outfit')) {
    $('div.selsect-an-outfit li').click(function() {

        // ...

        return false;
    }); // <-- Right there
}
```

Comment: The "missing" semi-colon is actually optional, that doesn't mean that it is a good idea to leave it out though.

Comment: Yeah. I've run into weird issues in IE with stuff like that. But you're right.  By the way, the trailing comma in array elements is even worse. That one seems very common :S.